# How to combine CSR and SSG - nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a product page. I want to use SSG for all products. (about 1000 products).
but each page have `related products` and `suggestion products` I want make them with CSR.

this my code:

```
const initialState = {
  relatedProducts: [] as LightGifttDto[],
  suggestionsProducts: [] as LightGifttDto[],
}
interface Props {
  gift: GiftDto;
}

export default function Gift(props: Props) {
  const {gift} = props;
  const [pageState, setPageState] = useState(initialState);
  //to scroll down of any where
  const commentRef = useRef(null)
  //to get related products and suggestion products
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const [relatedProducts, suggestionsProducts] = await Promise.all([
        getRelatedProducts(gift.id),
        getSuggestionsProducts(gift.id),
      ]);
      setPageState({
        relatedProducts,
        suggestionsProducts,
      })
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [])
  return (
    <ShopLayout>
      <GiftProvider value={gift}>
        <PriceGiftProvider>
          <ProductPage commentRef={commentRef}/>
        </PriceGiftProvider>

        <ProductCarouselSection
          products={pageState.relatedProducts}
        />


        <ProductComment commentRef={commentRef}/>

        <ProductCarouselSection
          products={pageState.suggestionsProducts}
        />
      </GiftProvider>
    </ShopLayout>
  );
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const giftslugs = await getTopGiftsSlugForServerSideGenerate();
  

  return { paths: giftslugs, fallback: "blocking" };
}

export async function getStaticProps({params}) {
  const slug = encodeURI(params.slug);
  const gift = await getGiftWithSlug(slug);
  return { props: { gift } };
  
}
```

But I do not know this way is correct or not for to combine SSG and CSR.

Comment: The correct way to combine SSG and CSR is to use the useSWR hook: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fetching-data-on-the-client-side